# Rollback of ExePackage if bootstrapper is cancelled / uninstall ExePackage if bootstrapper is cancelled

Tags: windows-services, wix3.11

**Background:**
As asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74574314/20599168), I have a large project which consists of a server component, client component and microservice hosting component. Each is packed in its own MSI.
The server component and the microservice hosting component each install a Windows service.
The server components' Windows service depends on the microservice hosting components' Windows service.

Everything is chained together and distributed by a setup bundle *.exe installer. In the installer, a customer can choose if he wants to install only the client, only the server or both (client and server).
At the end of the installation the customer is informed that everything went well (all files copied, all services running) (= success message) or not (= failure message with the possibility to send the log files to our help desk).

Updates are implemented as `MajorUpgrade`s since the setup consists of hundreds of files. Our customers expect that if an update fails, the setup "rolls back" to the previously installed version of the product (= the whole bundle).

**What lead to the problem?**
Since Wix v3 does not handle rollbacks of bundles the way I expect it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54744499)) -- only the MSI that triggered the failure is rollbacked, previously installed MSIs in the chain before are only removed -- we had to implement a few workarounds:

1. install the component, which most likely causes errors on a customer machine, first -- then install the other MSIs.
2. deal with the Windows service dependencies of the components later (= restart the server component service)

**The problem**
On an upgrade case, if a updated prerequisite (e. g. the Visual C++ redistributable) requires a reboot, the bootstrapper asks for the reboot and when the user confirms, the system restarts. That's fine, but:
*Our service component Windows service takes quite long to start (up to 5 minutes).*

This leads to the case that the setup updates the server component, but it's Windows service is still starting up.

To work around this, we decided to stop and disable the Windows service and enable it again after the upgrade is complete.

This lead to the following Wix source code:
Bundle.wxs

```xml
       <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="ServiceHandlingStop" />
            <PackageGroupRef Id="SqlExpress"/>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="vcredist"/>
            <!-- ... -->            
            <PackageGroupRef Id="Server"/>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="MicroServiceHost"/>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="ServiceHandlingStart" />
            <PackageGroupRef Id="Client"/>
        </Chain>
```

Fragment of the "service handling":

```xml
    <Fragment>
        <Variable Name="ServiceHandlingLogFilePath"
                  Value="%TEMP%\ServiceManagement.log"
                  Persisted="yes"
                  Hidden="yes" />
        <Variable Name="ServiceName"
                  Value="WCFHostService"
                  Persisted="yes"
                  Hidden="yes" />

        <util:ProductSearch Id="ServerSearch"
                            UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCodeId)"
                            Variable="ServerInstalledVersion"
                            Result="version"/>

        <PackageGroup Id="ServiceHandlingStop">
            <ExePackage Id="ServiceHandlingStopCall"
                        Compressed="yes"
                        CacheId="ServiceManagementStopv$(var.FileVersion)"
                        DisplayName="Service Management"
                        SourceFile="redist\Runner.bat"
                        InstallCommand="(^(net stop [ServiceName] ^|^| cd.^) ^&amp;^&amp; sc config [ServiceName] start= disabled) &gt;&gt; [ServiceHandlingLogFilePath] 2&gt;&amp;1"
                        UninstallCommand="(sc config [ServiceName] start= auto ^&amp;^&amp; net start [ServiceName]) &gt;&gt; [ServiceHandlingLogFilePath] 2&gt;&amp;1"
                        DetectCondition="ServerInstalledVersion = v$(var.FileVersion)"
                        Permanent="no"
                        Vital="no"
                        PerMachine="yes">
                <ExitCode Behavior="success" />
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>

        <PackageGroup Id="ServiceHandlingStart">
            <ExePackage Id="ServiceHandlingStartCall"
                        Compressed="yes"
                        CacheId="ServiceManagementStartv$(var.FileVersion)"
                        DisplayName="Service Management"
                        SourceFile="redist\Runner.bat"
                        InstallCommand="(sc config [ServiceName] start= auto ^&amp;^&amp; net start [ServiceName]) &gt;&gt; [ServiceHandlingLogFilePath] 2&gt;&amp;1"
                        UninstallCommand="(^(net stop [ServiceName] ^|^| cd.^) ^&amp;^&amp; sc config [ServiceName] start= disabled) &gt;&gt; [ServiceHandlingLogFilePath] 2&gt;&amp;1 || cd."
                        DetectCondition="ServerInstalledVersion = v$(var.FileVersion)"
                        Permanent="no"
                        Vital="yes"
                        PerMachine="yes">
                <ExitCode Value="0"
                          Behavior="success" />
                <ExitCode Behavior="error" />
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
```

If the setup bundle is closed by a user on upgrade during the "ServiceHandlingStopCall" action, the Windows service of the previous version stays disabled and stopped -- it looks like the uninstall part of "ServiceHandlingStopCall" is never executed.

I already tried to queue yet another custom "ServiceHandling" `ExePackage` that only has an UninstallArguments attribute to re-enable and re-start the Windows service, but it looks like the Runner.bat file for this always gets deleted (the log file ServiceHandlingLogFilePath states 'The batch file cannot be found.'.
But the bundle log states that it ran the rollback `ExePackage`:

```
[0A1C:1C0C][2023-06-01T15:33:29]i319: Applied execute package: ServiceHandlingRollbackCall, result: 0x0, restart: None
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:29]i301: Applying execute package: ServiceHandlingStopCall, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ServiceManagementStopv4.20.0.0\Runner.bat, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ServiceManagementStopv4.20.0.0\Runner.bat" (^(net stop ***** ^|^| cd.^) ^&^& sc config ***** start= disabled) >> ***** 2>&1'
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: Bootstrapper application aborted during EXE progress.
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0A1C:1C0C][2023-06-01T15:33:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0A1C:1C0C][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i319: Applied execute package: ServiceHandlingStopCall, result: 0x80070642, restart: None
[0A1C:1C0C][2023-06-01T15:33:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to execute EXE package.
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i351: Removing cached package: ServiceHandlingStopCall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ServiceManagementStopv4.20.0.0\
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i301: Applying rollback package: ServiceHandlingRollbackCall, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ServiceManagementRollv4.20.0.0\Runner.bat, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ServiceManagementRollv4.20.0.0\Runner.bat" (sc config ***** start= auto ^&^& net start *****) >> ***** 2>&1 || cd.'
[0A1C:1C0C][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i319: Applied rollback package: ServiceHandlingRollbackCall, result: 0x0, restart: None
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i351: Removing cached package: ServiceHandlingRollbackCall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ServiceManagementRollv4.20.0.0\
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d1c74bea-0d08-4583-bffb-f40e04384a38}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {d1c74bea-0d08-4583-bffb-f40e04384a38}
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i352: Removing cached bundle: {d1c74bea-0d08-4583-bffb-f40e04384a38}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{d1c74bea-0d08-4583-bffb-f40e04384a38}\
[165C:0E58][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d1c74bea-0d08-4583-bffb-f40e04384a38}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0A1C:1C0C][2023-06-01T15:33:30]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070642, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

**Question:**
How to implement the rollback of the "ServiceHandlingStopCall" `ExePackage` so on cancellation of the setup it enables and starts the Windows service again?
Is this related to [the issue that WiX v3 does not rollback ExePackages](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5950)?

Or if someone has an idea of how to tackle this whole Windows service start/stop/enable/disable mess, feel free to comment.

Thank you!